# Why aren't my private variables updated after using getter-setter methods?

Tags: java, scope, instance

I'm making a program that asks for user input to enter a name. I've done pretty much the same thing twice before. However, for some reason, the program is giving me `null` when I call the function to print it. I focused on only working on this before the `int` variables, but yes, they also had the same issue.

My code starts out like this

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int choice; 
        
        //Sets the student's name
        Student scholar = new Student(); //Access to Student.java
        Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter your name"); 
        String newName = nameInput.nextLine(); //applies the string to a variable
        scholar.setName(newName); //Calls a method to input the name
        exitTutor();
    }

    public static void exitTutor(){
        Student scholar = new Student();
        scholar.results(""); 
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class Student {
    private String studentName;

    public void setName(String studentName){
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public void results(String result){
        System.out.println("Final Results for " + studentName);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Final Results for null
```

I even copied and pasted the code I used in my other programs where it works, yet it was still `null`.

Edit: I added the results call. I understand that using `""` and a 0, but I'll replace those later with user input

Edit #2: I added a call to `exitTutor()`;

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example ... Setting the name via setter works fine. Seems you are using your class wrong ... But we won't know, because there is no call to `results` in the code you show ...

Comment: I should add that it's imperative that the Student class variables are not static.

Comment: You should add compilable code that shows your problem. If I add the missing parts, it works fine ...

Comment: Well, in `exitTutor` you are creating a new `Student` ... This has nothing to do with the `scholar` you created in `main` ...

Comment: There's now a call to `results`, but that's only in `exitTutor`, which itself is never called. cc @derpirscher

Comment: @SolomonUcko Well, obviously it has to be called from somewhere if there is an output ... So I suppose it's called from main and OP just didn't add that line of code ...

Comment: Your `exitTutor` needs to also refer to the scholar you are creating in `main`. Like this you are doing everything right but are not refering to the scholar and instead creating a second, new scholar in the method `exit` by itself. That new sholar must always be null since you never update it.

Comment: @derpirscher no it's called from outside that. Sorry, I'm a little sleep deprived. I added that now, and even made sure my program could run that. I didn't want to add the entire code because I felt that might that might waste everyone's time, but this didn't work out either. 

`exitTutor` can be called within and outside main via switches. I'm thinking if I can try implementing the `exitTutor` into main, as deleting the `Student` object makes `scholar.results` cause errors (I believe it's out of scope).

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 different `Student` instances:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice; 
        
        //Sets the student's name
        Student scholar = new Student(); // Create student 1
        Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter your name"); 
        String newName = nameInput.nextLine();
        scholar.setName(newName); // Set name of student 1
        exitTutor();
    }

    public static void exitTutor() {
        Student scholar = new Student(); // Create student 2
        scholar.results(""); // Prints the name of student 2, which wasn't set, so null
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

When you call `exitTutor()`, you completely ignore your previously created student with its assigned name. The first student instance you create is not in *scope* of the `exitTutor` method. In order to use the same student you create previously, you will want to pass it to the method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice; 

        //Sets the student's name
        Student scholar = new Student(); // Create student 1
        Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter your name"); 
        String newName = nameInput.nextLine();
        scholar.setName(newName); // Set name of student 1
        exitTutor(scholar);
    }

    public static void exitTutor(Student scholar) {
        scholar.results(""); // Prints the name of student 1, which was set
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

You can also assign the student to a field instead, but this is in most cases not what you want to do:

```
    private static Student scholar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice; 

        //Sets the student's name
        scholar = new Student(); // Create student 1
        Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter your name"); 
        String newName = nameInput.nextLine();
        scholar.setName(newName); // Set name of student 1
        exitTutor();
    }

    public static void exitTutor() {
        scholar.results(""); // Prints the name of student 1, which was set
        System.exit(0);
    }
```